# IP Scanning program Python 3

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, networking, ip-address

This is the code I made to scan IP addresses. I am new to python and just want to learn how I can optimize it. I know the subprocess is slower than others to IP scanning but if there is a way to make it faster I would like to know how. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
import subprocess
import datetime
hostname = input("Entrez la gateway de cette manière(example: 192.168.1)")
# Ask for gateway
while True:
    file_name = input("Comment voulez-vous appelez votre dossier?Sans espace ni   caratère spéciaux(example:file_name)")
    # Ask how the user want to name the file where the result of the scan will be

    if " " in file_name:
        print("Réecrire le nom sans espace")
    # check for spaces in the name file(impossible to create name files with spaces or special characters)
    else:
        break
with open(str(file_name) + ".txt", "w")as i:
    i.write("Start time" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    # print the start time of the scan process
    for scan in range(1, 255):
        i.write("-" * 100)

        ip_address = str(hostname) + "." + str(scan)
        ping_response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", ip_address, "-n", '1'],   stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
        #Ping the ip address

        ping_response = ping_response.decode()
        # (la réponse du ping est encoder , cette commande la decode)

        print("-"*100)
        print(ping_response)
        i.write(str(ping_response))
        if ip_address == hostname + "." + "254":

            i.write("End time" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            # print the end time of the scan process

            i.close()
            quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the `argparse` module for getting user input
2. Validate user input
3. Use `f"{string}"` or `"{}".format(string)` instead of manually concatting
4. No need to do `i.close()` as the `with` automatically closes the file
5. Use a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard
6. Add functions for re usability

## Revised Code

```
import subprocess
import datetime
import re

import argparse

def write_result(filename, ping):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(f"Start time {datetime.datetime.now()}")
        for result in ping:
            f.write(result)
        f.write(f"End time {datetime.datetime.now()}")

def ping_subnet(subnet):
    for addr in range(1, 255):
        yield subprocess.Popen(["ping", f"{subnet}.{addr}", "-n", "1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) \
                        .stdout.read()                                                          \
                        .decode()

def main(subnet, filename):
    write_result(filename, ping_subnet(subnet))

def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [options] <subnet>',
                                     description='ip checker',
                                     epilog="python ipscanner.py 192.168.1 -f somefile.txt")
    parser.add_argument('subnet', type=str, help='the subnet you want to ping')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--filename', type=str, help='The filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not re.match(r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})", args.subnet) \
       or any(a not in range(1, 255) for a in map(int, args.subnet.split("."))):
        parser.error("This is not a valid subnet")

    if " " in args.filename:
        parser.error("There cannot be whitespaces in the filename")

    return args.subnet, args.filename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*parse_arguments())
```

Comment: First thank you for the precious help! but where am I supposed to declare de subnet when i try to run the code i get this error:usage: labo3.py [options] <subnet>
labo3.py: error: the following arguments are required: subnet

Comment: try `python {scriptname} -h`

Comment: Example usage would be `python {scriptname} 192.168.1 -f somefile.txt`

Comment: Oh ok I understand now, (there's many things I've never used in your code I am going to learn how it works thank you!

Comment: Yeah my bad  I didn't see the beginner tag, if you have any question feel free to ask them and I will answer as best as I can :)

Comment: Thank you very much I will probably have question on it in the future, now I need to read tons of doc  :)